# Parser Error Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, google-maps

I have been struggling with this for sometime now and after reading several post I still can not for the life of me figure out whats causing this to bomb out. Essentially Im establishing a google map, then using a function to retrieve the places from a PHP database query I use, using Ajax. Here is the code for the function.

```
 function fetchPlaces() {
        alert('I started');

        var data = { 
            "action" : "test"

            };

        var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ''
        });

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "mapHandle.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.status == true) {
                    alert('ok');
                } else {
                    alert('error');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
            }
        })


    };


`
```

And here is the PHP page its directed at.

```
<?php       
    header('Content-Type: application/json');


    echo '{"name":"darian","lastname":"brown","age":87,"adress":{"21 somewhere street","my city","Australia"}}';
?>
```

Error Im Receing

> VM1979:70 Details: parsererror
>   Error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: You should use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON.

Comment: "address":["21 somewhere street","my city","Australia"]

Answer (score 4):

Your json is incorrect, the address seems to be wrong, you have an object there but you are separating the properties with comma, and not assigning values, try as follows which is what i believe you want:

```
echo '{"name":"darian","lastname":"brown","age":87,"adress":"21 somewhere street, my city, Australia"}';
```

Comment: That was successful by means of it threw an failed error versus a ajax error. after seeing that I can't believe I missed something that obvious. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem! glad to help :)